# Putting renderer.clear() at the end of render() makes my scene black

Tags: javascript, three.js

My code is like this:

```
function render() {
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
    renderer.clear();
}
```

I wonder why it makes my scene black. Is that because the color buffer is cleared before being actually rendered?

In this way it works well:

```
function render() {
    renderer.clear();
    renderer.render( scene, camera );
}
```

But how can I make sure the color buffer has been rendered before I call `clear()`?

I'm curious about the difference between clearing at the end and at the beginning.

Comment: Why do you need to clear color buffer **after** rendering?

Comment: @KirillDmitrenko I'm curious about the difference between clearing at the end and at the beginning.

Comment: Can you update your question with this?

Comment: what do you expect to happen? you render then you clear it so of course it's clear. maybe I'm not understanding the question

Comment: @gman I thought once I call `render()` the image will be rendered onto the screen and `clear()` won't affect what I actually see in the browser.

Comment: render() renders the scene into the canvas. clear() clears the canvas.

Comment: `I thought once I call render() the image will be rendered onto the screen and clear() won't affect what I actually see in the browser. ` what does this mean?

Comment: @pailhead Sorry for my poor English. I mean I thought `clear()` only clears the frame buffer but has no effect on the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between clearing renderer's framebuffer before and after rendering lies in the way WebGL content is being presented to a web page. The thing is WebGL is always at least double buffered (in WebGL Insights book guys from Mozilla say that in Firefox WebGL canvases actualy are triple-buffered). That means that within a `requestAnimationFrame` callback (`render` function in your case) all WebGL calls affect only a so-called back buffer. The other buffer (called front buffer) is unaffected. Then, when the callback ends, browser swaps buffers: the back buffer becomes front buffer, the front one becomes back buffer. The new front buffer is then used by the browser to draw the web page. The new back buffer is drawn to by WebGL next time `rAF` callback's called. Its important to note that the browser by default doesn't change contents of the buffer upon swapping them (`preserveDrawingBuffer` context option changes that though).

Going back to your question, the difference is that when you first render the scene and then clear the buffer you first will get strange results since the framebuffer contains rendering result of a same previously rendered frame (you won't see those results on the screen, they'll just be in the buffer's memory), and then you'll make all that irrelevant since you clear the buffer. After that the browser'll present clean buffer to the page as it is, or as black rectangle (or some different color depending on options of the renderer). However, if you clear first and then render a scene, you'll get correct results: first clearing eliminates relicts of a previous frame and then puts new content into it. Then browser presents it to the page.

So, to sum up: we usually clear framebuffer first to remove any traces of previous frames from so we start with a "clean slate" and then render stuff to it.

Comment: this answer makes no sense. There's no *you first will get strange results since the framebuffer contains rendering result of a same previously rendered frame*. Render and then clear is exactly analogous to `a = 123; a = 456;`. `a` now equals `456`. There's no point at which anything is *strange*?!?? Or else I'm not understanding your answer.

Comment: @gman Maybe I've put it ambiguously. I didn't mean "get" as in "see on screen" but as in "have in the framebuffer's memory just before clearing it". I'll try to make it clearer. Like in your example `a` **is** 123 at some point, we just don't see it.